# Interpreting ANOVA on regression function to determine model appropriateness

Tags: statistics, machine-learning, anova

I am working on a data set with two variables; age (x) and wage (y). I created a series of polynomial regression models to fit to the data and I am attempting to identify which model is best (and simplest) in predicting wage using age. I have learned that one way to determine this is to run an ANOVA on each model and interpret the corresponding p value/F statistic for each model. After running the ANOVA, I intuitively select models 2 and perhaps 3 as the models which meet my selection criteria. However, one of my reference sources suggests that model 4 would be the most appropriate model. Here is the output from the ANOVA:

```
Res.Df     RSS Df Sum of Sq        F    Pr(>F)    
1   2998 5022216                                    
2   2997 4793430  1    228786 143.5931 < 2.2e-16 ***
3   2996 4777674  1     15756   9.8888  0.001679 ** 
4   2995 4771604  1      6070   3.8098  0.051046 .  
5   2994 4770322  1      1283   0.8050  0.369682    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

I don't understand why model 4 would be the best model in this instance, when there are models with higher F statistics and lower p values to select from. Would this have anything to do with model variability? I'm clearly missing something in my understanding and am hoping someone from the community can help. I realize this may come across as a machine learning problem and apologize if this is the incorrect section to post in.

Many thanks for your help all.

Comment: One size fits all isn't a very good model and the highest level of significance isn't necessarily the best for just those two variables. IOW, does your model account for the difference between the wage of a 50 year old black woman versus a 50 year old white male? Do you see my point; other variables come into play.

Comment: Hi @PhilH, yes of course, and thank you for taking the time to comment. This is a basic example and one that isn't taking into account other variables that may affect the outcome. I'm more curious as to why the ANOVA is being interpreted the way that it is in the reference source. I suppose, to your point, significance is one measure of scoring how well a model fits.

Comment: IMO https://stats.stackexchange.com/ is a better place to ask about this.

Comment: thanks @StubbornAtom i'll move this there!

Comment: Do cross-link the two posts when you ask again.